# Build a CSV file out of 3 different RichTextBoxes entries

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, data-structures, stringbuilder

I am trying to find the best way or the right data structure to solve the following issue in C# Visual Studio:

I have 3 RichTextBoxes

[RichTextBoxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqtjm.png)

Each will accept a data like FirstName, Surname and country

I will take each first entry of each RichTextBox and put them in the same line using StringBuilder then loop to next and next until end

It should look like

FirstName1,Surname1,Country1

FirstName2,Surname2,Country2

and so on

```
            excelFile = new ExcelFile();
            var date = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var csv = new StringBuilder();

            var newLine = "FirstName, LastName, Country";
            csv.AppendLine(newLine);

            foreach (var name in rtextbox_firstname.Lines)
            {
              need to loop through each rich text box then add all to same data set (which not sure which would be good in my case) then loop thru to create the file
            }

            var path = "C:\\Users\\Shahi\\Desktop\\" + "run this " + "_" + date + ".csv";
            File.AppendAllText(path, csv.ToString());
```

Comment: Do you have same number of firstname, surname and countries in richtext box?

Comment: Yes, it must be same number of entries however I will try do some sort of if statement to catch any failures to not crash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of foreach, why can't you use simply a for loop,

```
excelFile = new ExcelFile();
var date = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var csv = new StringBuilder();

var newLine = "FirstName, LastName, Country";
csv.AppendLine(newLine);

//You can update exit condition if there are different number of entries in richtextbox
//Use for loop instead of foreach
for (int i = 0; i < rtextbox_firstname.Lines.Length; i++)
     csv.AppendLine($"{rtextbox_firstname.Lines[i]}, {rtextbox_surname.Lines[i]}, {rtextbox_country.Lines[i]}");


var path = "C:\\Users\\Shahi\\Desktop\\" + "run this " + "_" + date + ".csv";
File.AppendAllText(path, csv.ToString());
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that simple solution. Thank you very much, I went way too far I guess. I got it worked like charm. Cheers